# Split a string by Comma by excluding the ones inside Double Quotes

Tags: regex, string, kotlin, split, regexp-replace

I have this string in particular:

> 123,abc,true,true,true,false,true,false,false,false,123,"my
> name is : something('Jack'), email is 'abc@gmail.com' is already
> provided. The company's policy 'xyz', is
> beneficial.",ABCD,591633,1

I want to split the string by commas by excluding the commas inside the Double Quotes. So the Output that I am trying to produce here is

> [123, abc, true, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, 123,
> "my name is : something('Jack') email is 'abc@gmail.com' is
> already provided. The company's policy 'xyz' is beneficial.",
> ABCD, 591633, 1]

I have tried using other stackoverflow post's answers, but they DID NOT work for such string. Can anyone help me on how I can achieve this?

I'm trying to implement this in Kotlin.

One way I could think to get this is, first getting rid of commas inside the double quotes and then splitting the string by commas, but couldn't get the expected result.

Comment: Are you parsing a CSV file?

Comment: Yes, I am parsing a CSV file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're trying to parse a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file, it's almost always far better to use an existing library than to write your own code.  Advantages include:

- It copes with all the corner cases and subtleties that you don't have the time to learn about or support.  For example, what happens if the double-quote characters are themselves quoted?  What if the delimiter is a semicolon or tab or space or something other than a comma?  (Yes, that still gets called CSV, confusingly enough.  For example, Excel writes semicolons in some locales that have comma as the decimal separator.)  What about headers, line-breaks, comment lines, blank lines, escape sequences?  And can you handle and test all the different dialects of CSV that different programs write?
- It has been thoroughly tested, and proved by countless users.
- It's updated when standards change, bugs are found, or performance can be improved.
- It's commonly used so other developers may be familiar with it.

One example is Apache [Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/), which is free, open-source, and trivially easy to include in any Maven or Gradle project.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = '"Foo","Bar, baz","Lorem","Ipsum"',
    res = str.split(/,(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/);

console.log(res);  // [ '"Foo"', '"Bar, baz"', '"Lorem"', '"Ipsum"' ]
```

Comment: This regex works, but in kotlin you would need to create a Pattern and pass it into the split function. So first `val pattern = Pattern.compile(",(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)")`. Then `str.split(pattern)`

Answer (score -1):

I got it working with the following change

```
file.nextLine()
.replace(",(?=[^\"]*\"[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*$)".toRegex(), "")
.split(",")
```

Replaced the commas within the quotes with a "" and split the string with delimiter comma.

This gave me the expected output :-)

***but NOT RECOMMENDED***